# Machine learning: specific strategy learned because of playing against specific agent?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

First of all I found difficulties formulating my question, feedback is welcome.

I have to make a machine learning agent to play dots and boxes.

I'm just in the early stages but came up with the question: if I let my machine learning agent (with a specific implementation) play against a copy of itself to learn and improve it's gameplay, wouldn't it just make a strategy against that specific kind of gameplay?

Would it be more interesting if I let my agent play and learn against different forms of other agents in an arbitrary fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of having an agent learn by playing against a copy of itself is referred to as self-play. Yes, in self-play, you can sometimes see that agents will "overfit" against their "training partner", resulting in an unstable learning process. See [this blogpost by OpenAI](https://blog.openai.com/roboschool/) (in particular, the "**Multiplayer**" section), where exactly this issue is described.

The easiest way to address this that I've seen appearing in research so far is indeed to generate a more diverse set of training partners. This can, for example, be done by storing checkpoints of multiple past versions of your agent in memory / in files, and randomly picking one of them as training partner at the start of every episode. This is roughly what was done during the self-training process of the original AlphaGo Go program by DeepMind (the 2016 version), and is also described in [another blogpost by OpenAI](https://blog.openai.com/competitive-self-play/).

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was helpful to me!

Comment: @user6078387, if it was useful, please accept the answer. You can find more info on how to do it and why is important here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work